# Проблема с build settings unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игра в unity, для платформы android, но при попытке построить проект в build settings, я получаю ошибки. Как это исправить? Unity 2021.3.11f1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы сделали, после чего они появились?

Comment: @aepot Попытался построить проект.

Comment: Вы прикалываетесь? А до этого?

Comment: @aepot я новичок просто, изменил название компании, продукта, иконку и поставил портретный режим.

Comment: @aepot до этого, ничего не делал.